# Adding JWT to current application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt, bcrypt

I've been trying to research implementing JWT into my application and a little confused. Currently, I'm using BCrypt in order to Hash and Salt. My file looks like this in the User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  validates :username, :email, :password_digest, presence: true
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6, allow_nil: true }

  attr_reader :password

  after_initialize :ensure_session_token

  def self.find_by_credentials(email, password)
    user = User.find_by(email: email)
    user && user.is_password?(password) ? user : nil
  end

  def self.generate_session_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def password=(password)
    @password = password
    self.password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create(password)
  end

  def is_password?(password)
    BCrypt::Password.new(self.password_digest).is_password?(password)
  end

  def reset_session_token!
    self.session_token = User.generate_session_token
    self.save!
    self.session_token
  end

  def ensure_session_token
    self.session_token ||= User.generate_session_token
  end
end
```

What I'm trying to ask is would I need to create a new method to further encrypt the password output from using BCrypt? Like I can't find any articles where a user encrypts a user password with BCrypt then uses JWT. All I'm seeing is people mentioning adding BCrypt by adding has_secure_password to the user model and basically creating hashing methods with JWT instead.

My question is replace BCrypt with JWT or what are some recommendation in regards to securing a user password with both JWT and BCrypt? also, any beginner friendly articles would be appreciated.

Thanks for all your help and explanation.

Comment: My understanding is that JWTs are a form of authorization, not authentication.  So, the user's password wouldn't be related to the JWT at all.  Your JWT would replace a session cookie, so it's something you would use in a before action to authorize a user.

Answer (score 1):

JWT is quite a different way compared to the method of logging in a user and using sessions and cookies to authenticate future requests.

If you think of it like this, user comes to your application and goes to login (like normal, with [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for example). You receive their username and password on the login and check agasint the BCrypt hash in the database. If they successfully login, you then provide them with a JWT token. Inside this token is encoded their user id.

When they make future requests to your application (normally from an API) then they will provide the token instead of their username password. Your server has a secret and can decrypt this token to check if it is valid and can then use the user_id inside to know that it is the correct user. This will allow them to access any resources that they have access to.

JWT is normally used for javascript front ends or Smart phone apps that want to have long login times (rather than session or cookie). The token is also stateless so as long as the server has the secret, it can check its valid and decrypt it.

Here is a more detailed explanation: https://github.com/dwyl/learn-json-web-tokens

Here is a good guide for setting up JWT with devise: https://medium.com/@mazik.wyry/rails-5-api-jwt-setup-in-minutes-using-devise-71670fd4ed03